# Await a promise multiple times in parallel

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have some server API methods I call during startup of my application at different places, which can't be refactored in terms of where they are called, let's say `getSettings()` and `getSchedule()`. Both methods are based on a `login(): Promise<Account>` method as settings as well as the schedule are user-based.

Now I have solved the beginning of `getSettings()` and `getSchedule()` like the following:

```
class UserFunctions {
    private fetch_login: Promise<AccountItem> = undefined;
    async getSchedule(): Promise<any> {
        var account = getAccount();
        if (!account) {
            // No account loaded
            let isLogginIn = this.fetch_login;
            if (!this.fetch_login) {
                // Not logging in from any parallel method
                this.fetch_login = login();
            }
            account = await this.fetch_login;
            this.fetch_login = undefined;
        }
        
        // Now get schedule...
    }
}
```

The idea behind is that the `login()` function is only called once no matter how often it could be called. That's why I keep a reference on the Promise to await it multiple times. This works, but I noticed that sometimes when `login()` is done `getSettings()` gets earlier the okay to continue work and `getSchedule()` stays a few seconds until it continues executing. Sometimes it's the other way around and sometimes both methods return in the same time.

Here I have a print of the output:

> 06-05 16:46:08.126 27376 27397 I ReactNativeJS: Logging in back
>
> 06-05 16:46:08.690 27376 27397 I ReactNativeJS: Logged in back
>
> 06-05 16:46:08.696 27376 27397 I ReactNativeJS: Schedule downloaded
>
> 06-05 16:46:09.274 27376 27397 I ReactNativeJS: Logged in back

Do you have any idea how the code can be improved that once `login()` is done, both methods continue working?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got the right idea, but the logic needs a little tweaking:

```
    var account = getAccount();
    if (!account) {
        // No account loaded            
        if (!this.fetch_login) {
            // Not logging in from any parallel method
            this.fetch_login = login();
        }
        account = await this.fetch_login;
    }
```

Basically the idea is that you'll set `fetch_login` to have the value of the promise the first time it gets called. After that, you can `await` that same promise as many times as you need to.

Comment: It was wrong in the question here, but I updated the code here. It's fine in my code and login() is only called once.

Comment: @DevAttendant: The code in the question is still wrong: you're invoking `fetch_login()` as if it's a method, but it's a promise.

Comment: You're right, it's too warm here inside. But all of that is working in my real code. Updated post, thanks.

Comment: @DevAttendant: with all the differences between your actual code and the code you've posted, there's a strong likelihood that the behavior you're reporting is coming from one of those differences, and we won't be able to diagnose your problem from the information you've given. Try providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You're **calling** `fetch_login`. You should just be referring to it:

   ```
   account = await this.fetch_login; // <== No ()
   ```
2. Remove this line:

   ```
   this.fetch_login = undefined;
   ```

E.g.:

```
async getSchedule(): Promise<any> {
    var account = getAccount();
    if (!account) {
        // No account loaded
        if (!this.fetch_login) {
            // Not logging in from any parallel method
            this.fetch_login = login();
        }
        account = await this.fetch_login;
    }

    // Now get schedule...
}
```

You **keep** the promise resulting from the login attempt, so you can `await` it each time. (Nothing about `await`ing a promise prevents your doing so again.)

---

It seems like this should be handled at the level of `getAccount` and `login`, though, rather than within `UserFunctions`. `getAccount` and `login` appear to be global (within your app or module or whatever). I would probably have them manage this, with `getAccount` returning a promise:

```
var accountPromise = null;

function getAccount() {
    if (!accountPromise) {
        accountPromise = login();
    }
    return accountPromise;
}
```

then

```
async getSchedule(): Promise<any> {
    var account = await getAccount();

    // Now get schedule...
}
```

Example:

```js
var accountPromise = null;

function getAccount() {
    if (!accountPromise) {
        accountPromise = login();
    }
    return accountPromise;
}

function login() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("Logging in...");
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Logged in");
            resolve({}); // {} = the account
        }, 800);
    });
}

class UserFunctions {
    /*private*/ fetch_login/*: Promise<AccountItem>*/ = undefined;
    async getSchedule()/*: Promise<any>*/ {
        var account = await getAccount();

        // Now get schedule...
        console.log("Got account, getting schedule");
    }
}

// The first time it's used
const u1 = new UserFunctions();
u1.getSchedule(); // Logs in and gets schedule

// The second time it's used
setTimeout(() => {
    const u2 = new UserFunctions();
    u2.getSchedule(); // Gets schedule (already logged in)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You're right, I fixed it in the post, as I tried to create a simple code snippet to explain the situation. In my code it is looking like it's now and logging in is only appearing once in the console.

Comment: I fixed number 1, though it was only in demo code here, not in real code. About 2 I need to think first.

Comment: @DevAttendant - Note the second part of the answer, though. This really shouldn't be at the `UserFunctions` class instance level, if `getAccount` and `login` have greater scope than a `UserFunctions` instance.